# Как отменить setInterval при достижении определенного значения?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Здравствуйте.
Меняю setInterval'ом высоту блока. Хочу что бы он плавно появлялся. В итоге он появляется, но, как правильно отменить интервал с помощью clearInterval? Высота блока случайная.
Код такой:

```js
var height = randomInteger(70, 110); // при достижении этого значения, нужно отменить интервал
var j = 0;
var lightHeightInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName('graph-column-light')[0].style.height = j + 'px';
    j++
}, 5);
```

Пишу условие, что, если высота блока равно значению height, то clearInterval.

```js
if (elem.style.height == height) {
  clearInterval(lightHeightInterval)
;}
```

Это не работает.

Answer (score 4):

```
var height = randomInteger(70, 110);
var j = 0;

//поиск по DOM медленный, обращаемся один раз
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('graph-column-light')[0];

var idInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
    elem.style.height = j + 'px';
    j++;
    if (j == height) {
        clearInterval(idInterval);
    }        
}, 5);
```